# Divide 2 columns and create new column with results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with columns:

```
User_id PQ_played PQ_offered
 1           5        15
 2          12        75
 3          25        50
```

I need to divide PQ_played by PQ_offered to calculate the % of games played. This is what I've tried so far:

```
new_df['%_PQ_played'] = df.groupby('User_id').((df['PQ_played']/df['PQ_offered'])*100),as_index=True
```

I know that I am terribly wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with sample data that represents the entire problem (so with multiple rows per `User_id`, if we are to group), as well as the expected output?

Comment: What is your expected output? You may be looking for df.groupby('User_id').apply(lambda x: (x['PQ_played']/x['PQ_offered'])*100)

Comment: Expected output is User_id 1 '%_PQ_played' 33.33 User_id 2 '%_PQ_played'  16

Answer (score 4):

It's much simpler than you think.

```
df['%_PQ_played'] = df['PQ_played'] / df['PQ_offered'] * 100

         PQ_offered  PQ_played  %_PQ_played
User_id                                     
1                15          5     33.333333
2                75         12     16.000000
3                50         25     50.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda functions

```
df.groupby('User_id').apply(lambda x: (x['PQ_played']/x['PQ_offered'])*100)\
.reset_index(1, drop = True).reset_index().rename(columns = {0 : '%_PQ_played'})
```

You get

```
    User_id %_PQ_played
0   1       33.333333
1   2       16.000000
2   3       50.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @mVChr and think you are over complicating what you need to do. If you are simply trying to add an additional column then his response is spot on. If you truly need to `groupby` it is worth noting that this is typically used for aggregation, e.g., `sum()`, `count()`, etc. If, for example, you had several records with non-unique values in the `User_id` column then you could create the additional column using

```
df['%_PQ_played'] = df['PQ_played'] / df['PQ_offered'] * 100
```

and then perform an aggregation. Let's say you wanted to know the average number of games played of the games offered for each user, you could do something like

```
new_df = df.groupby('User_id', as_index=False)['%_PQ_played'].mean()
```

This would yield (numbers are arbitrary)

```
   User_id  %_PQ_played
0        1    52.777778
1        2    29.250000
2        3    65.000000
```